# Removing N Elements

Tags: python

How to write a code that returns a list with all elements that occurred N times removed?

I'm trying to write a python function duplicate(elem, N) which returns a copy of the input list with all elements that appeared at least N times removed. The list can't be sorted. For example ((2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5), 2) would return (1,3,5).

Comment: `mylist.count(x)` tells you the number of occurrences of x in your list.  If it's greater than one, then it is duplicated.

Comment: if `N` is 3, do you keep both instances of 4? or you just keep 1

Comment: @aws_apprentice you keep both instances of 4

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.Counter`

```
import collections

def duplicate(lst, n):
    counts = collections.Counter(lst)
    keep = {v for v, count in counts.items() if count < n}

    return [el for el in lst if el in keep]
```

Comment: @aws_apprentice because that's massively more expensive. `list.count` is `O(n)`, and you're doing it `n` times so you're at `O(n^2)`. `collections.Counter` is `O(n)`.

Comment: @aws_apprentice 2n != n^2, and if you're opting into less efficient solutions because it saves 2 LOC, you've got some strange priorities! I consider `list.index` and `list.count` to both be code smell.

Comment: @aws_apprentice whoops! Good catch :)

Comment: is there a way to do this without importing any libraries?

Comment: @hiphopfrog yes you can use `dict.setdefault` (which is what `collections.defaultdict` uses, which is what `Counter` is using under the hood), but there's no *reason* to do this without importing any libraries when `Counter` is the correct solution.

Comment: Question would prefer if there were no libraries imported

Comment: Any way to write the code with using just 'for' and 'if' loops? I've tried but keep getting an error

Comment: @hiphopfrog I won't help you write bad code. The solution is posted.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve your question by using `defaultdict` **(PS:** we can also use a normal dicts too if we want it):

```
from collections import defaultdict


def duplicate(data, n):
    counter = defaultdict(int)
    for elm in data:
        counter[elm] += 1
    return [k for k, v in counter.items() if v < n]


a = (2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)
print(duplicate(a, 2))
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5]
```

**PS:** If you want to compare my code and the Python's `collections.Counter` class code, visit this [collections in Python's Github repository](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/collections.py#L470). (Spoiler alert, `Counter` is using a `dict` not `defaultdict`)

Comment: Yup! If I recall correctly, `Counter` is basically just doing this under the hood.

Comment: Yes and i prefer `defaultdict` over normal `dict` in this situation. Less code and we can focus in the main problem.

Comment: I tend to eschew `defaultdict`s for `dict.setdefault`, but for the admittedly nonsense reason that it often saves me an import. This works great.

Comment: this removes dupes btw, if you put in `N = 3` it only returns a single `4` as opposed to returning both

Comment: @aws_apprentice and if `N = 10` should we return all the `2` too ? I think we need just return only the number ietself not all the occurences.

Comment: is there a way to do this without importing any libraries? Also, we need to return all occurrences

Comment: @hiphopfrog you can use a normal python `dict` instead of `defaultdict`. And can you add an example of your desired output ?

Comment: (('Hello', 'Bye', 'Bye', 'Hello', 'Bye', 1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 2), 3) == ('Hello', 'Hello', 1, 5, 7)

Comment: @hiphopfrog What's the logic of returning `'Hello`' and not returning `2` ?

Comment: Because 'Hello' did not occur AT LEAST N = 3 times. 2 occurred AT LEAST N = 3 times

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list comprehension here. Assuming elem is your list of values as input.

```
[x for x in set(elem) if elem.count(x) < 2]
```

Comment: This is almost certainly not what they're trying to do. For one thing: set construction will remove order (and duplicates!)

Comment: the set is to create the list of unique values in the input elem array to then run the count function on the original elem array, order does not matter and the removal of duplicates is intentional

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure that's what OP is looking for, see "The list can't be sorted" which I take to mean "order is important." Also it's not clear whether duplicates *should* be removed or not.

Comment: Ah I see, yeah I confused myself on the end goal. This solution isn't going to work if the OP is looking to return all values.